# How to add inventory to the same sales receipt in quickbooks

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add multiple pieces of inventory to a sales receipt in quickbooks.

so far, if I have 4 items, it creates 4 different sales receipts.

However, I want to make 1 sales receipt that contains 4 different items.

This is what I have so far, but I cant seem to find out the right code for this.

```
        public void SalesInfoAdd(IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet)
    {
        ISalesReceiptAdd salesReceiptAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendSalesReceiptAddRq();
        ISalesReceiptLineAdd salesReceiptAddNew = salesReceiptAddRq.ORSalesReceiptLineAddList.Append().SalesReceiptLineAdd;

        salesReceiptAddRq.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue(Form.name.Text);
        salesReceiptAddRq.IsPending.SetValue(true);
        salesReceiptAddRq.IsTaxIncluded.SetValue(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < Form.productID.Count; i++)
        {
            salesReceiptAddNew.ItemRef.FullName.SetValue(Form.productID[i].ToString());
            salesReceiptAddNew.ORRatePriceLevel.Rate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(Form.pricesList.Items[i]));
            salesReceiptAddNew.Quantity.SetValue(Form.QBqt[i]);
            salesReceiptAddNew.Desc.SetValue(Form.productsList.Items[i].ToString());

            //groupSalesReceipt.ItemGroupRef.FullName
            IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
        }
    }
```

For Anyone with this same problem, this was my solution(below), and it worked great.

Thanks

```
        public List<ISalesReceiptLineAdd> salesReceiptAddNew;

    public void SalesInfoAdd(IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet)
    {

        ISalesReceiptAdd salesReceiptAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendSalesReceiptAddRq();
        salesReceiptAddNew = new List<ISalesReceiptLineAdd>();

        salesReceiptAddRq.CustomerRef.FullName.SetValue(Form.name.Text);
        salesReceiptAddRq.IsPending.SetValue(true);
        salesReceiptAddRq.IsTaxIncluded.SetValue(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < Form.productID.Count; i++)
        {
            salesReceiptAddNew.Add(salesReceiptAddRq.ORSalesReceiptLineAddList.Append().SalesReceiptLineAdd);

            salesReceiptAddNew[i].ItemRef.FullName.SetValue(Form.productID[i].ToString());
            salesReceiptAddNew[i].ORRatePriceLevel.Rate.SetValue(Convert.ToDouble(Form.pricesList.Items[i]));
            salesReceiptAddNew[i].Quantity.SetValue(Form.QBqt[i]);
            salesReceiptAddNew[i].Desc.SetValue(Form.productsList.Items[i].ToString() +
                                            Form.QBsku[i].ToString());
        }
        IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);

    }
```

Comment: is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create multiple lines under one sales receipt.
You can use apiexplorer tool to test this use case.
Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD
Doc Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/salesreceipt

I have created the following SalesReceipt with 2 line items. PFB xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="b9bf137554a843cf8bd34865812daff6" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
   <ExternalRealmId>179017358</ExternalRealmId>
   <Object xsi:type="SalesReceipt">
    <Header>
     <DocNumber>9900</DocNumber>
     <TxnDate>2010-09-02</TxnDate>
     <Currency>USD</Currency>
     <CustomerId>537923</CustomerId>
     <ShipDate>2011-03-02</ShipDate>
     <TotalAmt>2500</TotalAmt>
     <DiscountAmt>0</DiscountAmt>
    </Header>
    <Line>
     <Desc>7th Item</Desc>
     <ItemId>434443</ItemId>
     <UnitPrice>67890</UnitPrice>
     <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Line>
    <Line>
     <Desc>8th Item</Desc>
     <ItemId>434443</ItemId>
     <UnitPrice>12345</UnitPrice>
     <Qty>2</Qty>
    </Line>
   </Object>
</Add>
```

View in QBD

[image]

Please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Omg...

XD I figured it out... but your comment helped me figure it out, so for that ill give you the plus.

For anyone reading this, ill update my answer in case anyone gets stuck with this dilemma.